# How do I search for an entry out of two SQL tables and know which table it came from?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, where-clause

I'm trying to find a specific entry. This entry can appear in only ONE of my two tables and will never repeat in either table.

Here is a scaled-down version example of my tables:

**Table 1:**

```
Date             Name              Room
2020/01/23       John              201
2020/01/22       Rebecca           203
```

**Table 2 (does NOT have the same amount of columns):**

```
Date             Name              
2020/01/23       Robert            
2020/01/22       Sarah
```

To find this entry, I need to specify a date and a name. You can assume names never repeat.

So let's say I want to find Sarah 2020/01/22

She could appear in either Table 1 or Table 2, and I don't know which one and I need to know which table she's in.

I'm not sure how I would do this in a single SQL query. So far I just have two separate ones:

```
SELECT date,name from Table1 WHERE name="Sarah" and date='2020/01/22'
```

and

```
SELECT date,name from Table2 WHERE name="Sarah" and date='2020/01/22'
```

Is there a way to do it in a single query that also tells me which table it came from? It could be another field or some indication that I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`, and add another column to each resulset, with a literal value that indicates the table name:

```
select 't1' as which, date, name from table1 where name = 'Sarah' and date = '2020-01-22'
union all 
select 't2' as which, date, name from table2 where name = 'Sarah' and date = '2020-01-22'
```